# Most efficient way to check string array and then write it into file

Tags: java, list, file

I need to check a `List` of `Strings` to contain certain predefined strings and - in case all these predefined string are contained into the list - I need to write the list to a File.

As a first approach I thought to do something like

```
if(doesTheListContainPredefinedStrings(list))
    writeListIntoFile(list);
```

Where the `doesTheListContainPredefinedStrings` and `writeListIntoFile` executes loops to check for the prefefinedStrings and to write every element of the list to a file, respectively.

But - since in this case I have to worry about performance - I wanted to leverage the fact that in the `doesTheListContainPredefinedStrings` method I'm still evaluating the elements of the list once.

I also thought about something like

```
String[] predefinedStrings = {...};

...

PrintWriter pw = new FileWriter("fileName");

int predefinedStringsFound = 0;

for (String string : list)
{
    if (predefinedStrings.contains(string))
        predefinedStringsFound++;

    pw.println(string);
}

if (predefinedStringsFound == predefinedStrings.length)
    pw.close();
```

Since I observed that - at least on the system where I'm developing (Ubuntu 19.04) - if I don't close the stream the strings aren't written to the file.
Nevertheless, this solution seems really bad and the file would still be created, so - if the list wouldn't pass the check - I'd have the problem to delete it (which requires another access to the storage) anyway.

Someone could suggest me a better/the best approach to this and explain why it is better/the best to me?

Comment: you should consider the probability of success. If in most cases all predefined strings will be in the list, your second solution seems valid. If not, you will loose performance as you are doing a lot of unnecessary (slow) writes to disk in which case the first option is better imo.

Comment: Assuming that you're in the 'usually successful' category from @Conffusion 's message, you can always write the file out to a temp directory (one which is auto-cleaned by your OS) and do a `Files.move` (which should be nice and quick assuming the temp directory is on the same drive as your other machine) in the case of success, and leave it there in the case of failures.  Saves you doing the delete directly.

Answer (score 1):

check the reverse case — *is any string from predefs in the strings-to-check-list missing?*

```
Collection<String> predefs;  // Your certain predefined strings
List<String> list;           // Your list of strings to check

if( ! predefs.parallelStream().anyMatch( s -> ! list.contains( s ) ) )
  writeListIntoFile(list);
```

The above lambda expression stops as soon as the first string from predefs can't be found in the strings-to-check-list and returns `true` — You must not write the file in this case.
It does not check if any additional strings are in the strings-to-check-list, that are not contained in the predefs strings.